# How do I check if an item exists without getting "IndexError: list index out of range"?

Tags: python, list

Let's suppose I have this list:

```
common_list = ['Potato', 'Tomato', 'Carrot']
```

I want to check if `common_list[3]` exists; if it doesn't, I want to add something to it. Here's what I tried:

```
if common_list[2] and not common_list[3]:
    common_list.insert(3, 'Lemon')
```

But it gives me the error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: can you be a little more specific on what you want to do? Is it "I want to append an element to a list" or is it more complicated ?

Comment: Just use a try/except construct. If the index is invalid you'll get an IndexError. Or, based on your example, why not use the list's *append* method?

Comment: I want to append it, but what would be the right expression in Python to say: "If does not exist"?

Comment: Thank you for recommending the "append" method!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends exactly what kind of check you want to perform. Here are some possibilities.

Check there are exactly three items:

```
if len(common_list) == 3:
    common_list.append('Lemon')
```

Check there are less than four items:

```
if len(common_list) < 4:
    common_list.append('Lemon')
```

Check there's no fourth item, or that the fourth item is present but set to `None`:

```
if len(common_list) < 4 or common_list[4] is None:
    common_list.append('Lemon')
```

Check that the list doesn't already contain `'Lemon'`:

```
if 'Lemon' not in common_list:
    common_list.append('Lemon')
```

Don't trigger and catch exceptions when you can avoid them with a simple `if` check. It's bad style. Exceptions are expensive and catching them is slow. Try to only use them for truly *exceptional* circumstances where you'd be surprised if an error actually occurred.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you will try try exception method?

```
common_list = ['Potato', 'Tomato', 'Carrot']
try:
    common_list[3]
except IndexError:
    common_list.insert(3, 'Lemon')
```